# How to fix the slowness and hanging that my PC faces?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Recently I replaced my 80GB Hard Disk with an 1000 GB Hard Disk in my CPU.
My CPU specs are: 
256MB RAM + 512 MB RAM Later added = 768 MB RAM
Single Core 2.93 Ghz

In the beginning, my PC came with an 80GB Hard Disk. But then it malfunctioned and I had to buy the 1TB hard disk. But now, after installing the new hard disk and installing Windows XP SP3, my PC slows down and hangs very often.

I am concerned if the 768 RAM not able keep up with 1 TB of hard disk space.

Comment: "I am concerned if the 7680 RAM not able keep up with 1 TB of hard disk space." - that doesnt make any sense at all.  

did you run an antimalware program?

Comment: Please remove the zero  after 768 in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of a number of years of experience with **Win XP**:

32 bit windows needs at least 2 GB (2000MB) RAM to function reasonably.
Even then a mindful & sensible use of software is of importance; large images in Photoshop, Word documents with lots of images, ... will be a challenge.

File indexing (for quick file search) is likely to cause fragmented memory(!) and slow response from the computer, at least wile the initial indexing is performed.

In earlier versions of Windows disk cache had a tendency to eat up the available RAM, google "vcache". This might not be valid for XP, but gives an idea of a possible problem.

Note that the last two paragraphs COMBINED gives a malicious combination.

Windows (XP and earlier at least) is inherently B.A.D. at handling low memory situations and similarly so with the system/swap file -drive(s) filling up.

Comment: Currently I have not installed any resource hungry application like Photoshop, etc. I only use Google Chrome even then I only use Google Chrome version 26.  I only download from internet, mostly videos and view them in VLC Player .i only browser the windows explorer nothing more.